# Knowing size of String object

Tags: java, string

How much memory allocated to a String object in both cases of

```
String s = new String("abc");
String s = "abc";
```

Comment: What language/framework/environment?

Comment: Size in characters or size in bytes?

Comment: They should be the same. Both are technically the same thing (AFAIK) unless maybe the compiler saves abc in Java's .data section instead and some smaller metadata than new String("abc") but it would probably do the optimization on that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Having many `s = new String("abc");` `s2 = new String("abc");` and so on will result in multiple allocating memory for this given string.

Using second way - `String s = "abc";`  `String s2 = "abc";` ... will allocate memory only once no matter how many times you will make "new" strings with this `abc` value.

In both ways one object should consume the same memory size.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = new String("abc");
```

The space used to represent this String allocated above depends on the platform.  For a 32-bit JVM, the String occupies roughly 10 32-bit words.  However, 5 of those words will be shared with the original String literal if you create the String this particular way ... at least with the standard Java 6 class libraries.

---

```
String s = "abc";
```

This does not allocate a String at all.  Rather it assigns the reference to an existing string literal to `s`.

Comment: Doesn't case 2 imply that allocation has occurred at some (other) point in time?

Comment: Well yes.  But that "other time" was when the class (or some other class) was loaded.  And it happens only once during the application's execution.  And the same thing would happen in case 1 also.